# Record Audio when api.ai process start listening

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I am using api.ai (google dialogflow) service to detect intent in my chat application. I also want to record audio file and send it to backend server.

I am able to do this thing with the following code snippet, but the problem is my application is properly working on vivo v9 (sdk 27), poco f1 (sdk 28),
but crash when i run it on emulator.

i debug the code and found if i comment recorder.startListening() method then my application works fine on all devices, but in this scenario i am not able to record the audio file.

here is my code snippet:

```
public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, AIListener{
    private AIService aiService;
    private static final int REQUEST_INTERNET = 200;
    AudioRecord recorder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
    //GCP STRAMING INITIALIZATION
    final AIConfiguration config = new AIConfiguration("******************",
            AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.English,
            AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System);

    aiService = AIService.getService(this, config);
    aiService.setListener(this);
    }

  //GCP STREAMING CODE
  public void createFile() {
    //Creating file
    File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    try {
        audiofile = File.createTempFile("sound", ".wav", dir);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("I", "external storage access error");

        }
    }

   @Override
   public void onResult(AIResponse response) {

    Result result = response.getResult();

    Log.d("I", "Query: " + result.getResolvedQuery() +
            "\nAction: " + result.getAction() +
            "\nParameters: " + parameterString);


}


@Override
public void onError(AIError error) {
    Log.d("Error", error + "");
    aiService.cancel();


}

@Override
public void onAudioLevel(float level) {

}

@Override
public void onListeningStarted() {



    try {

        recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);

        int i = recorder.getState();
        if (i == 1)
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        recorder.startRecording();
        isRecording = true;

        recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                writeAudioDataToFile();
            }
        }, "AudioRecorder Thread");

        recordingThread.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

@Override
public void onListeningCanceled() {
    try {
        aiService.cancel();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onListeningFinished() {

    if (null != recorder) {
        isRecording = false;

        int i = recorder.getState();
        if (i == 1) {
            recorder.stop();
        }
        recorder.release();

        recorder = null;
        recordingThread = null;
    }

    copyWaveFile(getTempFilename(), getFilename());
    deleteTempFile();


    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        File initialFile = new File(audioPath);
        //   File initialFile = new File("/storage/sdcard1/download/01 - Baarish (128 Kbps) - DownloadMing.SE.mp3");
        InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(initialFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[targetStream.available()];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = targetStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //upload to server
    uploadRecording(baos.toByteArray());



    }
}
```

I want use api.ai service as well as i also want to record audio file(.wav format) at the same time.